# How to randomly select from list within 24 hours once?

Tags: python, list

How do I randomly select from a list but only change values after every 24 hours.

Suppose I have: `main_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
and I want to see 5 random values, let's say `rand_list == 3,4,7,8,1` But  I don't want to update my `rand_list` for next 24 hours.

**What I am trying** :

```
reading current date : 14
```

Is there any way I can create indexes on the basis of date because it will not change values until date changes?

Like, If it's `14` today , it generates these indexes on the basis of 14: `4,2,8,1,3` . Now as soon it will be `14` , it will again generate same indexes, and I will see same list through-out the day. Is this something we can achieve within python and how?

EDIT:

```
day = 14

random.seed(day)
print(random.random())

print(random.random())

print(random.random())

print(random.random())

print(random.random())
it generates these 5 numbers : 0.10682853770165568 0.7025855239868555 0.6520420203142754 0.9403523895661179 0.27111522656032316
```

How do I map these constant numbers to List indexes ?

Comment: Have you tried using `random.seed` with the day of the month? https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed

Comment: @EdWard That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Hey thanks , I am reading about it . thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @EdWard I'd also add the month and year somehow, else the lists will be identical  every month/year. Like `seed = day + month*32 + year*366`

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you want new random numbers only once every 24 hours, why don't you draw the numbers only once every 24 hours? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am fetching matches from an API and I want to show randomly 5 matches through out the day

Comment: @AwaisArshad In that case (fetching from API) caching the result once will be a better option. If "fetching" means to make an URL request. You can store the result in a json file or use pickle (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to store an object.

Comment: How is this related to list indices all of a sudden? Are you aware of ``random.sample``?

Comment: You are using `random.seed` incorrectly. You set it only once and then call `random.random() `whenever you need a new random number. Every time the program then starts it will generate the same random sequence for successive `random.random()` calls if the seed is the same.

Comment: @DanielF yes , correct . but how do I map these 5 numbers to indexes

Comment: @MisterMiyagi random.sample generates a different list everytime , it is being called .or Is there anyway ?

Comment: If you have 9 options to choose from, generate them by `int(random.random() * (9-1))`. Or use `random.sample(range(9), k=5)` like @MisterMiyagi suggests.

Comment: @DanielF I am trying thanks , I really appreciate . yes it's working but it is generating some duplicates as well . I am sure I can use that hint

Comment: You're right. `random.sample` doesn't have this problem. See the suggested answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `random` module has a lot of flexibility.  If you want 5 choices you can get them all at the same time.

```
import random
random.seed(day)
rand_list = random.choices(main_list, k=5)
```

If you'd rather have indexes into your main list rather than values from it, that's easy too.

```
rand_indexes = random.choices(range(len(main_list)), k=5)
```

Comment: This will yield the same lists every month.

Comment: @DanielF that depends on the definition of `day`, doesn't it?  The question doesn't go into any detail on how it's derived.